# Is it possible to upload only upload a dialogflow agent to a raspberry pi without the Google Assistant?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi3, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I'm uploading an agent I've been working on to a raspberry pi, but I'm wondering if Google/ dialogflow offers the same type of option as AWS where you can upload your own personal agent from AWS Lex without Alexa ( In this case, Dialogflow agent without the Google Assistant). If this is possible, how would I go about this?

If possible, can you also set custom 'awake' phrases?

I'm new to the whole raspberry pi setup so if I'm completely mistaken by all of this please let me know!

Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly use a Dialogflow agent on a device or application through a [client library](https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks#v2_client_libraries). This is different from the [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview), which uses the entirety of the Google Assistant.

There's no built-in support for custom wake phrases through Dialogflow. That'd need to be something that you do yourself, perhaps using a popular library like [Snowboy](https://github.com/Kitt-AI/snowboy).